# Creation of Gradle based web application in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm trying to create a gradle based java project in Intellij IDEA.

Steps are below:

Opening Intellij IDEA, `Community edition` > `New project...` > `Gradle` > selecting `Auto import`, create directories for empty content roots and use default gradle wrapper.

Now project has been created and added Webapp(inside WEB-INF created) folder to java directory.

I need to know the following:

- What do I need to add in `build.gradle`?
- How and where to configure server tomcat?
- How to run the build.gradle?

Please help me finish this.

Comment: already tried https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin?

Comment: Usually, you don't create a gradle project using IntelliJ. You create a gradle project, using the documentation provided by Gradle, by simply editing the build.gradle file, and you open it in IntelliJ, which uses the gradle API to analyze the structure of the project and allow you to compile it from IntelliJ. You can launch gradle tasks from IntelliJ, but that won't do anything more than running them from the command line.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmWxo7K4Q0w

Answer (score 1):

I am new to all of this and I was trying to do the same thing, so I did some research and I hope this will help you.

1. You can imagine build.gradle as a build script, although strictly speaking it is a build configuration script. You run it by using the gradle command. The gradle command looks for a file called build.gradle in the current directory. The build script defines a project and its tasks.
   When you create the Gradle project, it should be created by itself so I don't think you should do anything about it.
2. Do Alt+Ctrl+S > Build, Execution, Deployment > Application Servers and add your server.
3. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html Here is the Gradle documentation, I hope it will help with the 3rd step))